# java random number that is randomly 0 or 1

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a random number that is zero or one but my code always returns one:

*It needs to be replicable, so I should be able to set the seed and get the same 0 or 1 whenever I need it in the future.*

```
    // value after setting seed
    System.out.println("Object after seed 0: " + RandomNumberGenerator(20, 0, 1) );
    System.out.println("Object after seed 1: " + RandomNumberGenerator(10, 0, 1) );
    System.out.println("Object after seed 2: " + RandomNumberGenerator(22, 0, 1) );
    System.out.println("Object after seed 3: " + RandomNumberGenerator(93, 0, 1) );
    System.out.println("Object after seed 4: " + RandomNumberGenerator(04, 0, 1) );

}


public static int RandomNumberGenerator(int seed, int min, int max) 
{
       // create random object
       Random randomno = new Random();

       // setting seed
       randomno.setSeed( seed );

       return randomno.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

I don't understand what is going wrong there.

Comment: Why can't you just use `Math.random()`?

Comment: "random number between 0 and 1" is `0.1` among values you expect or you want only integers?

Comment: `java.util.Random.nextBoolean() `

Comment: but what about seed?

Comment: Try doing `randomno.nextInt(1)` This will give you either 0 or 1. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @WyattLowery It's exclusive on the top bound. So `nextInt(2)` returns either 0 or 1

Comment: @snickers10m that doesn't work- always returns `1`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, so it's possible that all the seeds that you have chosen happen to give the same result. Have you tried any other values?

Comment: @Michael why did you delete your post? I was about to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer could've been revealed by a further investigation into your problem. You've chosen five isolated test cases. Here's a larger search:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        System.out.println("Seed " + i + ": " + RandomNumberGenerator(i, 0, 1));
}
```

And from this we discover that seeds up to 4095 output 1, and after that 0's start to appear.

I encourage you to do expansive tests like this in the future.

Comment: yes, that is wise- in the future i'll do that. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `Random` instance and call its `nextDouble` method. It returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
public static int randomBit(long seed){
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    return r.nextDouble() >= 0.5? 1 : 0;
}
```

Also, if you're unfamiliar with the question mark symbol, it's called the ternary operator. It's essentially a compressed `if-else` statement.

Comment: but it needs to be consitent- repeatable i mean- so i should be able to set the seed- you know what i mean?

Comment: You should use `>=` instead of `>` to get an equal distribution. `Math.random` returns a value that is `0.0 <= n < 1.0`, so `0.5` belongs to the upper half.

Comment: what about setting the seed?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English For the record, this isn't an answer to your original question. It's just a more compact version of your original code. The output is still all ones.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English I'm not trying to be salty, but why did you accept it then?

Comment: becasue I thought it would be useful for others

Comment: @S.Matthew_English That's what upvote is for. The accepted answer should directly provide an answer to the original question.

Comment: What number should be the seed?

Comment: @parsecer it can be any number you want. looking back on this post though, you should probably use another way. just know that this function will give you the same random bit for any given seen. so you'll have to keep giving different seeds if you want different random bits.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of `seed` you used.

If you test your code with:

```
for (int i=1; i<10000; i++){
    if (RandomNumberGenerator(i, 0, 1)==0){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

You will see that `0` was returned only for seeds in range `4096`-`8703`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using nextInt on java.util.Random. There are no integers between 0 and 1.
Also keep the seed random or you'll get the same result in every run.


Your code works fine, assuming you're trying to get a random number in a range (min, max).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");
        System.out.println("Object after seed 0: " + RandomNumberGenerator(20, 0, 10) );
        System.out.println("Object after seed 1: " + RandomNumberGenerator(10, 0, 10) );
        System.out.println("Object after seed 2: " + RandomNumberGenerator(22, 0, 10) );
        System.out.println("Object after seed 3: " + RandomNumberGenerator(93, 0, 10) );
        System.out.println("Object after seed 4: " + RandomNumberGenerator(04, 0, 10) );
    }

    public static int RandomNumberGenerator(int seed, int min, int max) {
        // create random object
        Random randomno = new Random();

        // setting seed
        /*randomno.setSeed(seed);*/

        return randomno.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```